# How to attach observers to a subject in react?

Tags: reactjs, observable

My App.js looks roughly like this:

```
<HorizontalNavigation />
<DataPanel />
```

The *HorizontalNavigation* component contains a Button to export the *DataPanel* containing charts into a PDF File. This already works fine. Now there is one tiny thing I need to do on the *Chart* components before I export them.

I am a react beginner, but when I understand correctly a basic solution would be to lift state up to a common ancestor of *HorizontalNavigation* and *DataPanel*. That would feel weird as I would have to reach down that state to a lot of intermediate components from *DataPanel* to the actual charts components. Also they would all be rerendered when this is not necessary at all.

What I had in mind is to use an observable pattern where the PDF export button notifies all charts to do their thing before exporting. How would you design such a pattern in react? The PDF Export button would be my subject to which the charts observers had to attach. But as I don't have a reference to the subject, how do observers attach?

As I'm a react beginner there might be a much more simple solution I don't see yet. So I also appreciate suggestions for other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is state transfer between component. Have a look at below link

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. +1 for leading me to context. When reading this https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context though, I don't think it fits quite well to solve the problem. For now I'm just using custom events on document: `document.addEventListener`